# Table not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table in modal

here is html code of it

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Город</th>
        <th scope="col">Регион</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="cities" style="overflow: auto;"></tbody>
```

And I get data from back end and generate table in js Like this

```
function GetCity() {
let citiesurl = '/cities/index';
$.ajax({
    url: citiesurl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#cities").empty();
        var list = data;
        for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
            var tableData = '<tr>' + '<td>' +
                (i + 1) +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="cityId" style="display:none">' +
                list[i].Id +
                '</td>' +
                '<td > ' +
                list[i].Name +
                '</td>' +
                '<td > ' +
                list[i].RegionName
                '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' +
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="">' + 'Подтвердить' + '</button>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#cities').append(tableData);
        }
    }
})
```

}

But all rendering great,  instead of button.

Any errors in console. Where can be error?

Comment: First, I don't see you closing the table, Second, you have way more `td` than you have `th`?. Also its kinda hard to know 100% what the problem is when you just say "Table not rendering correctly"

Comment: You're missing the `+` after `list[i].RegionName`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals would improve the readability of your code greatly, and reduce the chance of typos like this.

Answer (score 0):

there is issue with your table header. you have not add header for Region name and button.

try below code for header row

```
<tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Город</th>
        <th scope="col">Регион</th>
        <th scope="col">Region Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Button</th>
    </tr>
```

and after  close the table tag

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply make use of `Template Strings` template strings are enclosed in ``` back-tick (``) ```
replace your code with the code below

```
function GetCity() {
let citiesurl = '/cities/index';
$.ajax({
url: citiesurl,
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
processData: false,
success: function (data) {
    $("#cities").empty();
    var list = data;
    for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
      var tableData = `<tr>
        <td>
          ${ i + 1 }
        </td>
        <td class="cityId" style="display:none">
          ${list[i].Id}
        </td>
        <td>
          ${list[i].Name}
        </td>
        <td>
          ${list[i].RegionName}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info id="">Подтвердить</button>
        </td>
      </tr>`;

      $('#cities').append(tableData)
    }
}
})
}
```

this would work
click [This Link](http://wesbos.com/template-strings-html/) to know more about template strings